# Как вывести рейтинг в топе каталога?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь реализовать вывод рейтинга товара на странице с перечнем товаров.

Погуглив обнаружил, что в шаблоне каталога нет такой возможности, но она есть в компоненте новости, поэтому её можно скопировать от туда.

Если можете, то, пожалуйста, опишите подробно, как это сделать.

**Обновление**

Код вывода рейтинга:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:iblock.vote",
    "stars",
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $arItem['ID'],
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => "",
        "MAX_VOTE" => "5",
        "VOTE_NAMES" => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => $arParams['VOTE_DISPLAY_AS_RATING'],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams['CACHE_TIME']
    ),
    $component,
    array("HIDE_ICONS" => "N")
);
```

Добавил в `catalog.top/.default/template.php`, но результата никакого

Comment: попробуйте сами, если не получится покажите, что сделали, как должно быть, и что получилось у вас.

Comment: код вывода рейтинга https://jsfiddle.net/pf0fgmm9/ добавил в catalog.top/.default/template.php, но результата никакого

Answer (score 1):

Прописал в catalog.top/.default/section/template.php и всё заработало